# Purpose of Android Back button, is it OK or Cancel?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development, even to the androidOS, this is a more of a experience question on how do I approach on a OK or Cancel for a list of choices, Let's say a list of languages with a name and a checkbox next to it.

There's a back arrow button at the bottom of screen for each app, does that mean **Cancel** or that means I'm OK with the selection? I also noticed a toolbar back button, does that mean **OK** or **Cancel**? (attached screenshot).

What's the expectation of user for each of these back buttons so I can program my app accordingly?

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me where else to go and ask this question, if it's not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see hitting back as neither **OK** nor **Cancel** but a mechanism to navigate back to a previous `Activity` or `Fragment`. I usually refer to the back button to the left of the toolbar as the "in-app" back button, where as the system back button as the "system" back button, or "hardware" back button depending on the device.

Comment: ok, how do design or approach a layout with OK button, any screenshot would be appreciated.

Comment: I would have a look at Dialogs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Comment: so is it ok to have a save and cancel button under a long list, let's say list of countries?

Comment: by the way I placed two buttons under `ListView` but they are not showing, do I need to put them inside a container like `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

It normally means cancel, you can change that with this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed{
 //anything you want here
  }
```

Comment: so what other UI and where should I provide a button that means OK, any screenshot would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the default behavier of the toolbar back arrow button with this code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    try {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home: {

                //anything you want here
                return true;

            }

            case R.id.settings: {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```